# Working with XML in Excel

Tags: xml, excel, schema

I have a number of existing XML files with the schema and format defined within.I want to be able to copy this to Excel to make the data within the file editable. So I want to take a XML completed file today and populate with different values for the existing fields within tomorrow.
I have copied the XML file into my Excel file and I have two scenarios that seem to happen. I have copied the XML into Excel by dragging the XML file into Excel and selecting "Use the XML Source task pane.. Is this correct?

1. On one XML file - The schema copies into Excel and I can see the fields on the right hand side in the XML Source window. I copy the elements in to Cells A1 etc - once this is done it seems all the elements have NS1: pre-appended to the title. Also once the data is populated it is not exportable. 'Cannot save or export XML data. The XML maps in this workbook are not exportable. I am trying to export using the developer tab, XML and Export.
2. On another XML file - The schema copies into Excel and I can see the fields on the right hand side in the XML Source window. I copy the elements in to Cells A1 etc - once this is done it seems all the elements are copied across fine names match the element in the XML window. However once the data is populated it is not exportable. 'Cannot save or export XML data. The XML maps in this workbook are not exportable. I am trying to export using the developer tab, XML and Export.

Any help in how to use an existing XML format in Excel to make the fields  editable would be greatly appreciated. If this is not clear or you need further details please let me know.

Comment: Why not use an XML editor?

Comment: Hi Siraj - completely new to XML - can you explain? I have the structure of the file however I want something robust to be able to change the variables in the components frequently.

Comment: See this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_XML_editors. Try this for starters: [XML Notepad by Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7973)

Answer (score 1):

- Open Excel 2016
- Click on tab 'Developer'
- Use the Button 'XML Maps'
- Use the Button 'Add' to add your XML schema file (.xsd) - (You should see the XML Map on the right panel)
- Right click for example on the first entry
- Use 'Map element' (I always forget this step ... The first line should now be filled with the header information)
- Go back to tab 'Developer' in the area 'XML'
- Click on 'Import'

Comment: Python would not be something I would be using for this. I will look at the links from Office included, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the exact structure of your XML file but excel can only handle one dimensional XML data. I was never able to export a modified File again as valid XML files. Excel also likes to get the Schema before the actual data import as XSD files.

Most usesful Artikels to that Theme:

[Office Help](https://support.office.com/de-de/article/%C3%9Cberblick-%C3%BCber-XML-in-Excel-f11faa7e-63ae-4166-b3ac-c9e9752a7d80)

[Another Office Help](https://support.office.com/de-de/article/Zuordnen-von-XML-Elementen-zu-Zellen-in-einer-XML-Zuordnung-ddb23edf-f5c5-4fbf-b736-b3bf977a0c53)

I do not know how flexiple you are but for me i could only realise it with Python. Mit lxml.